# Any way for a ToolTip to trigger a MouseEnter event?

Tags: wpf, tooltip, mouseenter

I have a control with a tooltip. What i want is that when I hover over the control and the tooltip opens: if I then enter the tooltip with the mouse - this will trigger a mouseEnter event in order to trigger some other action. The closest I am to finding a solution to this is adding a ToolTipClosing event on the control with the trigger ... but this will fire as soon as I leave the control - even if my mouse doesn't enter the tooltip.
(Triggering a MouseEnter event on the tooltip itself doesn't seem to get fired at all)

Here's an example: (where I want to change the background of the border if I enter the tooltip)

XAML

```
<Border Height="300" Name="dummyBorder"
                        Width="200"
                        Background="Red" /> 
    <Label ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="3000"
                           Content="Hover over here"
                           ToolTipService.ShowDuration="4000"
                           ToolTipService.Placement="Right"
                           ToolTipClosing="Label_ToolTipClosing"
                           Width="100"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           Margin="10">
        <Label.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip Name="tt"  MouseEnter="ttBorder_MouseEnter">
                <Border Background="Brown"
                        Name="ttBorder"
                        MouseEnter="ttBorder_MouseEnter"
                        Width="100"
                        Height="50">
                    <TextBlock Text="This is a tool tip." />
                </Border>
            </ToolTip>
        </Label.ToolTip>
    </Label>
```

CodeBehind: (neither of these work)

```
private void Label_ToolTipClosing(object sender, ToolTipEventArgs e)
{
    if (tt.IsMouseDirectlyOver)
    {
        dummyBorder.Background = Brushes.Aqua;
    }
}

private void ttBorder_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    dummyBorder.Background = Brushes.Aqua;
}
```

I specifically want to use a tooltip and not a popup. Is this possible?
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well (after 9 months and no answer) I guess that there is no way then. (Unless proven otherwise)

Comment: MouseEnter does not work because IsHitTestable is always set to "false" for the parent Popup that hosts the tooltip: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ToolTip.cs#05775d1d4906ee8d 
On top of that, toolips apparently do not support StaysOpen = true, so there is no way to change the value of this property. Would have liked this too :(

Answer (score 0):

you will want to try something like this:

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
<CommandBinding Command="ChangeColour" 
   CanExecute="ChangeCanExecute"
   Executed="ChangeExecuted" />
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

inside your tooltip tag:

```
<MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding ChangeColour}"/>
```

then in your codebehind:

```
private void ChangeCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  e.CanExecute = true;
  e.Handled = true;
}

private void ChangeExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  dummyBorder.Background = Brushes.Aqua;
  e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: i'm not 100% sure on hooking up command in code behind as i do all my wpf with mvvm model. Did this way give any errors?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandbinding.aspx  this has a nice example for creating binding with code behind. Hope that helps!